# Loading Raw image with Image I/O objective C return wrong resolutions

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I'm trying to load RAW image to an iOS project for displaying. Currently, I'm using this piece of code to load the raw image.

```
CFDictionaryRef optionsRef = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) @{
                                                                  //                                                               (id) kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat: @YES,
                                                                  (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
                                                                  (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
                                                                  (id) kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : @(MAX(SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH) * ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale))
                                                                  };

        CGImageSourceRef imageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageUrl, NULL);

        if (!imageSourceRef)
            return nil;

        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                                 nil];
        CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSourceRef, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
        if (imageProperties) {
            NSNumber *width = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
            NSNumber *height = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
            NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %@ x %@ px", width, height);
            CFRelease(imageProperties);
        }
```

The problem is, this code works flawlessly with some images, while it behaves strangely with others. For example, with one image I load, it show the width is 128 and the height is 96 , while the correct width height are 4320 × 3240.

I'm not sure what is the problem here because all I did was just load the image to CGImageSourceRef. :(

Answer (score 0):

By raw you mean camera raw? (E.g. Nikon NEF files?)

As far as I know iOS does not have a raw image parsing engine. The only thing it will be able to do is to load the embedded JPEG thumbnail. You are probably seeing the size of the thumbnail, not the size of the full raw image.

Disclaimer: I've never tried to open a camera raw image in iOS, so my answer about what iOS is doing is based on imperfect memory of what I've read.

Comment: Hi Duncan,

Yes I'm trying to read Raw Image (.NEF, .CR2...) and so far, I have been using this code to successfully read some RAW images (mostly .CR2 and several .DNG) with the above code. The others I can read too but the output images' resolution is not correct at the original.

If iOS is indeed cannot load Raw Image, then why are there successful cases here? I'm not sure what is the image config that allow iOS to read full resolution or not

Answer (score 0):

Nikon has libraries available for download, and I think they are in source form.  Probably C or C++, so it would take a little work to compile them and figure out how to use them from iOS but it should be possible.  You should be able to find them on the Nikon website.